# Application insights make the app freeze on startup

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights, template10

I'm building a UWP application for Windows 10 using Template10. I would like to use MS Application Insights. In my project, I have references to: `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` (2.0.0), `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PersistenceChannel` (1.2.3), `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsApps` (1.1.1). In the App constructor, I have to following code:

```
public App()
{
    WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync();

    InitializeComponent();
    SplashFactory = (e) => new Views.Splash(e);

    #region App settings

    _settings = SettingsService.Instance;
    RequestedTheme = _settings.AppTheme;
    CacheMaxDuration = _settings.CacheMaxDuration;
    ShowShellBackButton = _settings.UseShellBackButton;

    #endregion
}
```

I have also added a correct InstrumentationKey from Azure to the `ApplicationInsights.config` like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">
    <InstrumentationKey>my-key</InstrumentationKey>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

However, when I launch my app, it simply hangs at the app logo. When I comment the `WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync();` line out, the app works normal.

I have tried removing and readding the mentioned references from the project, removing and reinstalling Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio, but without a success.

When I create a new Blank App (Universal Windows), Visual Studio sets up the Application Insights automatically and it works as expected. But I cannot get it to work with my existing project.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The story around using Application Insights in UWP apps is being deprecated in favor of HockeyApp, and there is a known issue with AI 2.0.0 on UWP.

See https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/210

Comment: I even tried to downgrade the Application Insights package to 1.2.3., that way the app works, but the Insights don't :( However, your link lead me to an [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/transitioning-mobile-apps-from-application-insights-to-hockeyapp/), which says that since 15th April MS will no longer be accepting new UWP apps using AI and shutting down the service completely on 15th June. So, seems like all my effort just went down the drain. I still don't understand, how they can replace AI with such an inferior product (HockeyApp).

Answer (score 1):

Just a moment ago I had exactly the same problem and I finally managed to make this work. So change dependencies in project.json to look like that:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PersistenceChannel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsApps": "1.0.0"
},
```

If this won't help I also recommend adding instrumentation key to WindowsAppInitializer:

```
WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync("YOURKEY");
```